# PHP. Upload .gif file to server

Tags: php

My assignment requires me to let users upload .gif file extensions to a folder, and display them after they upload it.

I got the form and processing page, but I cant seem to get them to work. I set the permissions on the directory to rwxrwxrwx to test it out.

Upload file code:

```
<html>
  <head>
<title>Assignment 7 Part II -- Art Gallery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="a7a2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000">
    Your file: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload it">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Assignment 7 Part II -- Art Gallery Results</title>
      </head>
      <body>

      <?php
      $uploadDir = 'images/';
      $uploadFileDir = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);                                                   
      if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile'])) {
          if($_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK ||
          $_FILES['uploadFile']['mime'] != "image/gif") {
          print "<p>File not uploaded successfully!</p>";
          print "<p>Please make sure the file has the correct file extension: .gif</p>"; 
          print "<p><a href='a7p2.php'>Try uploading again</a>";
          var_dump($_FILES['uploadFile']['error']);
          die;
          } else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], $uploadFileDir) or die("Can't move file to $uploadFileDir");   
          print "<p>Success!</p>";
          }
      }

      $uploadedFiles = glob("/students/ryan/php/images/*.gif");
      if($uploadedFiles != false) {
          print "<p>Here are pictures from the art gallery: </p>";
          foreach($uploadedFiles as $file) {
          $url = "http://hills.ccsf.edu/~ryan/images/" . substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
          print "<p><img src=\"$url\"></p>";
          }
      } else {
          print "There are no pictures in the art gallery";
      }
      ?>

      </body>
    </html>
```

or same code, link to the code below:

http://pastebin.com/JNxwy323

Comment: Could you give details as to **how** it's not working?

Comment: It keeps saying file not uploaded successfully. Please make sure file has correct file extension. Try uploading again

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump` on the whole `$_FILES['uploadFile']` when you see that is set. See what does it contain.

Comment: Right before you check the mimetype, do `var_dump($_FILES['uploadFile']['mime'])`. What does that output?

Comment: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "Rotating.gif" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(2) ["size"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 3):

It is not safe to rely on the MIME type that the browser tells you the file is. Instead, you should check to see if the file is what it is supposed to be. In this case:

```
if( !@imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'])) {
    // file is not a valid GIF image
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use tmp_name instead of name for the move_uploaded_file it should be

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadFileDir) or die("Can't move file to $uploadFileDir");
```

also instead of $_FILES['uploadFile']['mime'] != "image/gif") {

it should be $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'] != "image/gif") {

Comment: Nauto mo ako kupal